# .on click does not return .closest of "e"

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I am trying to get the text inside a `<h4>` that is closest to my clicked icon `<i>`

The following registers the click OK, but it does not return the value inside the h4. Instead, it returns a very long array of details as you can see, too long for Codepen:

```
<p class="icon heart">
  <i>icon</i>
</p>
<h4>this text</h4>


$('body').on('click', '.icon.heart i', function(e){
    var property = [];
    console.log('clicked!');
    console.log($(e).closest( ".intro-text h4" ));
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/pboYvZ

EDIT:

I have updated the HTML to be more representative of my code layout. How can I access the content inside the `<h4>`?

https://jsfiddle.net/0jsxjqzx/3/

Comment: You're `<i>` element would be better expressed as a `<button>` (better semantics, better accessibility)

Comment: Your code pen has no class `intro-text` also `e` is an event object, not a DOM element.

Comment: You have a paragraph element which doesn't have content that looks like a paragraph. Italic text with no text. And a sub-sub-sub-heading *after* something that relates to it. Your markup doesn't make a whole lot of of sense. You'd probably be better off with something like: `<h4><button><img src="heart.svg">Favourite</button> this text</h4>`

Comment: @Quentin my markup was meant to just be a quick demonstration. I have added a new link with my actual HTML

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that `e` is an Event object, not a DOM Element.

You, presumably, mean `this` or `e.target`

---

You then have a second problem (which I didn't notice at first because you failed to include the HTML in the question, I fixed that for you).

Look at [the documentation of closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

The `h4` is not an ancestor of the italic text! So it won't be found.

You need to go up to the paragraph and then find its sibling instead.

```
$(this).closest("p").next("h4");
```

Comment: or `e.currentTarget` (which might be better in some cases).

Comment: `e.currentTarget` also produces the same result.

Comment: @user1486133 try something like `$(this).closest('.intro-text').find('h4');`

Comment: I have updated with a better example of my full HTML in the JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the closing parenthesis on the last `console.log`.
`h4` is not a parent of `i,` so `closest` won't work, you may want to use `nextAll` .

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.iconheart').on('click', function(){
        var property = [];
        console.log('clicked!');
        console.log($(this).nextAll( "h4" ).html());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="iconheart">
  <i>icon</i>
</p>
<h4>this text</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.icon.heart i', function() {
    var property = [];
    console.log('clicked!');
    console.log($(this).closest(':has(.intro-text)').find('h4').html());
  });
});
```

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cn8trrhn/